# Is there a way to assign a name to a singleton in the local scope?

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a method that returns a singleton.

```
// Window.h    
static Window &getSingleton();

// Window.cpp    
Window &Window::getSingleton()
{
    static Window singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

Coming from `Objective-C` I'm used to assigning singletons to local scope variable names, for example.

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

But doing a similar thing in `C++` causes a new object to be created.

```
Window window = Window::getSingleton();
```

This happens because the copy constructor is called, in this case `Window(Window const &windowCopy)`.

Is there a way around this, or do I have to always call my singleton method when I need to interact with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++,

```
Window window = <some expression>
```

means something along the lines of "construct an object of type `Window` from the value of `<some expression>`. `Window::getSingleton()` evaluates to an lvalue reference to `Window`, and that could be used to initialize a new `Window` object (except for the fact that `Window` is not copy constructable.)

What you need to do is refer to the static object created in the `Window::getSingleton()` function. The function itself returns a reference. All you need to do is use a reference to `Window` on the LHS:

```
Window& window = Window::getSingleton();
      ^
```

Comment: Well that easy. Not used to the reference symbol being put there from the `C` days.

Comment: @MorganWilde C doesn't have references, but C++ recycles the `&` symbol to denote reference types. This is completely unrelated to the address-of operator `&`, with which it often gets confused.